# WiFi connection keeps dropping after short time

Tags: wireless, network-manager, connection

WiFi card worked fine for nearly a year until recently.  Now it keeps dropping and reconnecting.
I have tried shutting off power management but did not resolve issue.  Card is Realtec PCI card.
I'm still pretty green on terminal commands, so go easy on me.  Thanks

From `sudo journalctl`:

```
Jan 06 08:59:04 paul-MS-7B86 NetworkManager[914]: <info>  [1609945144.8386] device (wlp39s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jan 06 08:59:04 paul-MS-7B86 NetworkManager[914]: <info>  [1609945144.8387] device (p2p-dev-wlp39s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jan 06 08:59:07 paul-MS-7B86 NetworkManager[914]: <info>  [1609945147.9164] device (wlp39s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Jan 06 08:59:07 paul-MS-7B86 NetworkManager[914]: <info>  [1609945147.9165] device (p2p-dev-wlp39s0): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Jan 06 08:59:07 paul-MS-7B86 NetworkManager[914]: <info>  [1609945147.9396] device (wlp39s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Jan 06 08:59:07 paul-MS-7B86 NetworkManager[914]: <info>  [1609945147.9396] device (p2p-dev-wlp39s0): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> associating
Jan 06 08:59:08 paul-MS-7B86 NetworkManager[914]: <info>  [1609945148.2695] device (wlp39s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> disconnected
Jan 06 08:59:08 paul-MS-7B86 NetworkManager[914]: <info>  [1609945148.2696] device (p2p-dev-wlp39s0): supplicant management interface state: associating -> disconnected
Jan 06 08:59:18 paul-MS-7B86 NetworkManager[914]: <info>  [1609945158.2719] device (wlp39s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jan 06 08:59:18 paul-MS-7B86 NetworkManager[914]: <info>  [1609945158.2720] device (p2p-dev-wlp39s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jan 06 08:59:19 paul-MS-7B86 NetworkManager[914]: <warn>  [1609945159.6149] device (wlp39s0): Activation: (wifi) association took too long
Jan 06 08:59:19 paul-MS-7B86 NetworkManager[914]: <info>  [1609945159.6149] device (wlp39s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 06 08:59:19 paul-MS-7B86 NetworkManager[914]: <info>  [1609945159.6155] sup-iface[0x55946362f120,wlp39s0]: wps: type pbc start...
Jan 06 08:59:19 paul-MS-7B86 NetworkManager[914]: <warn>  [1609945159.6174] device (wlp39s0): Activation: (wifi) asking for new secrets
Jan 06 08:59:19 paul-MS-7B86 NetworkManager[914]: <info>  [1609945159.6194] device (wlp39s0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 06 08:59:19 paul-MS-7B86 NetworkManager[914]: <info>  [1609945159.6199] device (wlp39s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 06 08:59:19 paul-MS-7B86 NetworkManager[914]: <info>  [1609945159.6202] device (wlp39s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'Linksys20403_5GHz' has security, and secrets exist>
Jan 06 08:59:19 paul-MS-7B86 NetworkManager[914]: <info>  [1609945159.6203] Config: added 'ssid' value 'Linksys20403_5GHz'
Jan 06 08:59:19 paul-MS-7B86 NetworkManager[914]: <info>  [1609945159.6203] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Jan 06 08:59:19 paul-MS-7B86 NetworkManager[914]: <info>  [1609945159.6203] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-70:86400'
Jan 06 08:59:19 paul-MS-7B86 NetworkManager[914]: <info>  [1609945159.6203] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK WPA-PSK-SHA256 FT-PSK'
Jan 06 08:59:19 paul-MS-7B86 NetworkManager[914]: <info>  [1609945159.6203] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
Jan 06 08:59:21 paul-MS-7B86 NetworkManager[914]: <info>  [1609945161.3376] device (wlp39s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Jan 06 08:59:21 paul-MS-7B86 NetworkManager[914]: <info>  [1609945161.3376] device (p2p-dev-wlp39s0): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Jan 06 08:59:21 paul-MS-7B86 NetworkManager[914]: <info>  [1609945161.3625] device (wlp39s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Jan 06 08:59:21 paul-MS-7B86 NetworkManager[914]: <info>  [1609945161.3625] device (p2p-dev-wlp39s0): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> associating
Jan 06 08:59:21 paul-MS-7B86 NetworkManager[914]: <info>  [1609945161.3974] device (wlp39s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
Jan 06 08:59:21 paul-MS-7B86 NetworkManager[914]: <info>  [1609945161.3975] device (p2p-dev-wlp39s0): supplicant management interface state: associating -> associated
Jan 06 08:59:24 paul-MS-7B86 NetworkManager[914]: <warn>  [1609945164.1965] sup-iface[0x55946362f120,wlp39s0]: connection disconnected (reason -4)
Jan 06 08:59:24 paul-MS-7B86 NetworkManager[914]: <info>  [1609945164.2016] device (wlp39s0): supplicant interface state: associated -> disconnected
Jan 06 08:59:24 paul-MS-7B86 NetworkManager[914]: <info>  [1609945164.2016] device (p2p-dev-wlp39s0): supplicant management interface state: associated -> disconnected
Jan 06 08:59:24 paul-MS-7B86 NetworkManager[914]: <info>  [1609945164.3018] device (wlp39s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jan 06 08:59:24 paul-MS-7B86 NetworkManager[914]: <info>  [1609945164.3018] device (p2p-dev-wlp39s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jan 06 08:59:37 paul-MS-7B86 NetworkManager[914]: <info>  [1609945177.7858] device (wlp39s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Jan 06 08:59:37 paul-MS-7B86 NetworkManager[914]: <info>  [1609945177.7859] device (p2p-dev-wlp39s0): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Jan 06 08:59:37 paul-MS-7B86 NetworkManager[914]: <info>  [1609945177.8024] device (wlp39s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Jan 06 08:59:37 paul-MS-7B86 NetworkManager[914]: <info>  [1609945177.8024] device (p2p-dev-wlp39s0): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> associating
Jan 06 08:59:37 paul-MS-7B86 NetworkManager[914]: <info>  [1609945177.9000] device (wlp39s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
Jan 06 08:59:37 paul-MS-7B86 NetworkManager[914]: <info>  [1609945177.9001] device (p2p-dev-wlp39s0): supplicant management interface state: associating -> associated
Jan 06 08:59:44 paul-MS-7B86 NetworkManager[914]: <warn>  [1609945184.6159] device (wlp39s0): Activation: (wifi) association took too long
Jan 06 08:59:44 paul-MS-7B86 NetworkManager[914]: <info>  [1609945184.6160] device (wlp39s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 06 08:59:44 paul-MS-7B86 NetworkManager[914]: <info>  [1609945184.6166] sup-iface[0x55946362f120,wlp39s0]: wps: type pbc start...
Jan 06 08:59:44 paul-MS-7B86 NetworkManager[914]: <warn>  [1609945184.6184] device (wlp39s0): Activation: (wifi) asking for new secrets
Jan 06 08:59:44 paul-MS-7B86 NetworkManager[914]: <warn>  [1609945184.6211] sup-iface[0x55946362f120,wlp39s0]: connection disconnected (reason -3)
Jan 06 08:59:44 paul-MS-7B86 NetworkManager[914]: <info>  [1609945184.6213] device (wlp39s0): supplicant interface state: associated -> disconnected
Jan 06 08:59:44 paul-MS-7B86 NetworkManager[914]: <info>  [1609945184.6214] device (p2p-dev-wlp39s0): supplicant management interface state: associated -> disconnected
Jan 06 08:59:44 paul-MS-7B86 NetworkManager[914]: <info>  [1609945184.6217] device (wlp39s0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 06 08:59:44 paul-MS-7B86 NetworkManager[914]: <info>  [1609945184.6224] device (wlp39s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 06 08:59:44 paul-MS-7B86 NetworkManager[914]: <info>  [1609945184.6229] device (wlp39s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'Linksys20403_5GHz' has security, and secrets exist>
Jan 06 08:59:44 paul-MS-7B86 NetworkManager[914]: <info>  [1609945184.6230] Config: added 'ssid' value 'Linksys20403_5GHz'
Jan 06 08:59:44 paul-MS-7B86 NetworkManager[914]: <info>  [1609945184.6230] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
```

Comment: Have you recently updated the system by chance? If so, you may need to boot with a previous kernel. The simplest way to display do this is to press and hold the [Shift] key while booting, then choose something that uses the 5.4 kernel rather than 5.8.

Comment: Follow the "interface state" `disconnected, scanning, authenticating, associating, disconnected`. The other end is hanging up on you. Bad password, wrong method (WEP/WPA2)?